# Category description update using repository - M2

Tags: magento2, category-attribute

Using this I can update the category description but I want to update using the repository.

Working good with factory method:

```
$category_Id = 6;
$category = $this->categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($category_Id);
$category->setDescription("Test1/4"" Test° ");
$category->save();
```

I want to use the repository class, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository;
 */
protected $categoryRepository;
//eventually replace with interface if you want to


...

$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $storeId);
$category->setDescription("Test1/4"" Test° ");
$this->categoryRepository->save($category);
```

Surrounding with try catch to make sure to handle the exception if the category doesn't exist is a must have too.

Answer (score 0):

try{

$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $storeId);
$category->setDescription("Test1/4"" Test° ");

$this->categoryRepository->save($category);

}

catch(\Exception $e){

print_r($e->getMessage());
}